# Error in MapReduce job taking avro file and outputting a sequence file

Tags: hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, avro

I have a mapreduce job which takes an avro file of type `T` and is supposed to output pairs of form  as a sequence file. This job has only a mapper and here is code for the mapper and the driver program:

The mapper:

```
public class AvroReaderMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, AvroValue<ContentPackage>, Text, Text> {


@Override   
public void map(LongWritable k, AvroValue<T> record,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

       //some processsing

    }    

}
```

The driver program:

```
 public class SeqFileGenerator extends Configured implements Tool {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new SeqFileGenerator(), args);
    System.exit(res);

}

@Override
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {

//Job configuration
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(getConf());
    job.setJarByClass(SeqFileGenerator.class);
    job.setJobName("Sequence File Generator");

    //1-set the input and output path
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("in"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("out"));

    //2-set the mapper and reducer class        
    job.setMapperClass(AvroReaderMapper.class);

    //3-set the input/output format
    AvroJob.setInputValueSchema(job, ContentPackage.SCHEMA$);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);        
    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);               

    //4-run the job
    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    return 0;
}
```

}

When runs, it gives me the following error message:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroValue
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set correct input format for job in driver class. It assumes TextInputformat by default.

Try adding below line in driver class

job.setInputFormatClass(AvroKeyInputFormat.class);

Comment: I added that line and now it gives a different error message:

java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected...

Comment: This seems to issue associated with API difference between  Hadoop 1 and Hadoop 2. Can you try using old mapred API

Comment: The reason I chose the new API is that I can define a mapper whose input is an avro file while it is output is not. But I'm under the impression that in the old api I have to stick to AvroMapper class to define my mapper and there is no way (or at least I don;t know) to configure it to not have an avro file as the input. Right?